# how can I mass delete many rows from a table in Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-delete

Given a MySQL table with a nullable "PhotoUrl" field, some of the rows have this field blank (empty string), if members upload photos, the "PhotoUrl" should be showing something like `abc.com/acc.jpg`.

Now I would like to mass delete all those rows having blank string as the "PhotoUrl" field content.

how can I do that? Thank you.

Comment: Rephrased to emphasis the question is all about SQL detete.

Answer (score 0):

You can try doing a blanket deletion:

```
DELETE
FROM photos
WHERE COALESCE(PhotoUrl, '') = '';
```